# Components losing functionality upon being re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

This is my React Hook:

```
import {React, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './Student.css';

function Student(props){

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
    let match = searchQuery(props.nameSearch, props.student.firstName, props.student.lastName, props.tagSearch, tags);
    useEffect(()=>{
        let input = document.getElementById(tagBar);
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById(tagButton).click();
        }
        });

        
        match = searchQuery(props.nameSearch, props.student.firstName, props.student.lastName, props.tagSearch, tags);

    },[tags])

    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    function addTag(){
        let input = document.getElementById(tagBar);
        let tagList = tags;
        if (input.value != ""){
            setTags([...tagList, input.value]);
            input.value = "";
        }
    }

    function searchQuery(nameSearch, firstName, lastName, tagSearch, tags){
        let foundName = false;
        let foundTag = false;
        if (nameSearch == ""){
            foundName = true;
        }
        if (tagSearch == ""){
            foundTag = true;
        }

        if (firstName.toLowerCase().includes(nameSearch) || lastName.toLowerCase().includes(nameSearch)) {
            foundName = true;
        }

        tags.forEach(t => {
            if (t.includes(tagSearch)) {
                foundTag = true;
            }
        })

        return (foundName && foundTag);
    }

    let avg = 0;
    props.student.grades.forEach(grade => avg += parseInt(grade));
    avg = avg/(props.student.grades.length);

    let tagBar = "tagBar"+props.student.id;
    let tagButton = "tagButton"+props.student.id;

    let tagDisplay = tags.map((t, index) => {
        return <span key={t+index} className="tag">{t}</span>;
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {match ? 
                <div key={props.student.id} className="student">
                    <div className="avatar">
                        <img src={props.student.pic}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info">
                        <div className="fullName">
                            {props.student.firstName.toUpperCase()} {props.student.lastName.toUpperCase()}
                        </div>
                        <div className="nonName">
                            <div>
                                Email: {props.student.email}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Company: {props.student.company}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Skill: {props.student.skill}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Average: {avg}%
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                {open ?
                                    <ul className="grades">
                                        {props.student.grades.map((grade, index) => {
                                            return (<li key={grade+index}>Test {index+1}: {grade}%</li>)
                                            }
                                        )}
                                    </ul>
                                    :
                                    null
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div className="tags">
                                <div>
                                    {tagDisplay}
                                </div>
                                <input type='text' id={tagBar} className="tagBar" placeholder="Add a Tag"/>
                                <button type="submit" id={tagButton} className="hiddenButton" onClick={addTag}></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* If this was not required to be a button, I would have used + - images */}
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>{!open ? "+" : "-"}</button>
                </div>
                :
                null}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Student;
```

TL:DR - my component basically loads a bunch of student data and allows me to add tags to each one.
I can then filter out which students to load based on their name or tags associated with them.

On first load - everything works perfectly fine
Problem: after I start filtering out students (and they unrender), when I bring them back by clearing the search query, those students that disappeared can no longer add new tags. While as long as any student does not get filtered out, they can continue to add more tags. Search function itself works as intended throughout. What is causing this issue? and Why cuz it REALLY doesn't make sense to me why I would suddenly lose functionality

Comment: Don't use `addEventListener` in React when you can do it with the JSX instead...

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: you have several things which may create unexpected behavior. you run a useEffect adding a listener which never gets removed, and to his hook runs when tags changes, which is an array of objects. when you filtrr students, but tags are the same, the useEffect does not run again and you do not bind the event listener